# How to translate command-line into python code

Tags: python, command-line

I am currently working with python and I have some real trouble with the syntax.
I wanted to include a Cura command-line into my script but I do not know how to actually parse the line so that the command will be executed out of my Blender Script.
My code is the following and I really do not know if this is even valid:

```
def main(context):
    blend_file_path = bpy.data.filepath
    directory = os.path.dirname(blend_file_path)
    target_file = os.path.join(directory,bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath) +'.stl')
    bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=target_file)   

cevar = 'CuraEngine slice -j "C:\\Programme\\Ultimaker Cura 4.5\\resources\\definitions\\fdmprinter.def.json"' +' -l ' + directory + bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath) +'.stl +o '+ directory + bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath) +'.gcode'
os.system(cevar)
```

Comment: [plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a 3rd party module and doesn't ship with blender.  However it's easy to install and IMO greatly simplifies calling external commands.  Welcome to blender stack exchange. Look forward to your future questions as they become more blender specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code

```
import subprocess

cmd_args = [
    "CuraEngine",
    "slice",
    "-j",
    "C:\\Programme\\Ultimaker Cura 4.5\\resources\\definitions\\fdmprinter.def.json",
    "-l",
    f"{os.path.join(directory,bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath))}.stl",
    "+o",
    f"{os.path.join(directory, bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath))}.gcode",
]

output = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```